# How can I require a parameter to be typed as a union, and not just as a member?

Tags: typescript

Consider this example of a function that takes a union type:

```js
const isNull = (value: string | null) => value === null
```

How can I allow only this kind of usage (where the value is possibly null):

```js
const maybeNull = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'value' : null

isNull(maybeNull)
```

While disallowing this (where the value is definitely not null):

```js
const definitelyNotNull = 'value'

isNull(definitelyNotNull) // should error
```

Comment: You could do something like this: https://tsplay.dev/wXzvDm, but the error message isn't great.

Comment: @Oblosys this is what I was looking for, thanks. Can you submit as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this cleanly you'd need some kind of negated type (see for example [issue 4183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183)), which is not possible in TypeScript, but as a workaround you can make `isNull` generic and validate that `null` extends the parameter type:

```
type MaybeNull<T> = null extends T ? T : never

const isNull = <T>(value: MaybeNull<T>) => value === null
```

This works for the example applications, though the error isn't amazing.

```
const maybeNull = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'value' : null

isNull(maybeNull) // Allowed

const definitelyNotNull = 'value'

isNull(definitelyNotNull)
// Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5vaW)

Comment: I actually couldn't get this working in combination with a type predicate on isNull, any ideas for that?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't see how you could turn this `isNull` into a type predicate. Can't tell for sure, but it might not be possible.